# TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable and put csv file didn't work

Tags: python, loops, csv

im try to put my loop numpy data Modus_citra into csv file, but i've tried using numpy and using normal write csv didn't work

```
import glob
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array
import csv
import pandas as pd




def find_mode(np_array) :                                    
        vals,counts = np.unique(np_array, return_counts=True)    
        index = np.argmax(counts)                                
        return(vals[index])                                      

folder = ("C:/Users/ROG FLOW/Desktop/Untuk SIDANG TA/Sudah Aman/testbikincsv/folderdatacitra/*.jpg")
for file in glob.glob(folder):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    rows = image.shape[0]
    cols = image.shape[1]
    middlex = cols/2                    
    middley = rows/2                     
    middle = [middlex,middley]
    titikawalx = middlex - 10             
    titikawaly = middley - 10
    titikakhirx = middlex + 10           
    titikakhiry = middley + 10
    crop = image[int(titikawaly):int(titikakhiry), int(titikawalx):int(titikakhirx)]
    c = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    H,S,V = cv2.split(c)
    Modus_citra = (find_mode(H))
    data = (Modus_citra)
    with open("foo.csv", 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(data)
```

error =  'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable

foo.csv = from pictures
60
40
19
11
please can someone help me ? i Appreciate every help

Comment: What should the final `foo.csv` look like?

Comment: inside the csv file there will be modes from the loop write in columns

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put sample of this CSV file there (not picutre, text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the edit, you can try:

```py
folder = "C:/Users/ROG FLOW/Desktop/Untuk SIDANG TA/Sudah Aman/testbikincsv/folderdatacitra/*.jpg"

all_data = []
for file in glob.glob(folder):
    # ...
    Modus_citra = find_mode(H)
    all_data.append(Modus_citra)  # <-- add the numpy.uint8 to the all_data list

# after the loop write the data to the CSV file:
with open("foo.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for data in all_data:
        writer.writerow([data])
```